# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.CompletionStatusChanged

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I have a code which watches a particular folder for any file drops. On file drop, the file would be picked up for further processing.

Lately I get below exception. I'm not sure what's causing this exception or how to avoid it because it occurs intermittently and can't be replicated. Also unsure if this is occurring on file drop or simply when the watcher is polling the folder.

```
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length
Stack:
   at System.String.CtorCharPtrStartLength(Char*, Int32, Int32)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.CompletionStatusChanged(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
```

Below is my sample code:

```
 {
        // Code goes here

    _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    _watcher.Path = _scanDirectory;
    _watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite |      NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

    if (_watchSubTree)
    {
       _watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
    }

    // Add event handlers.
    _watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);
    _watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);
}
```

Comment: Do you have this code in asp.net page?

Comment: This code is part of ClassLibrary in an ASP.Net application

Answer (score 1):

You should create a console application that hosts your code. This server side code should not be part of an ASP.Net application, because of life cycle issues.

Try to check if the problem still occurs while running your code from a console application. Also check, if the useraccount that runs your program has file system access to the specified path.